# Http Put method not working in AngularJS with headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I am trying to use put method in http angularJS i am getting an error

Error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url]. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

My Code is :

```
var newRentalUrl = serverURL;
var dataObj = JSON.stringify(JSONDATA);

$http.put(newRentalUrl, dataObj, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  },
}).success(function(responseData) {
  try {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log(responseData);
    //$state.go('payment');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }
  $ionicLoading.hide();
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  console.log(data);
});
```

On the server side, the method is received as options

> 2015-10-21T05:37:02.947517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info
>   method=OPTIONS path="/v1/home/xx" host=xxxxxx.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=xxxxx-498d-4026-a39a-xxxxxxx fwd="xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=481

Comment: have you researched the error to understand what it means?

Comment: yes I did and this error is that put method is not catch up by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Change Content-Type to 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

And if it is a cross-origin resource  request you need to add set the CORS header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin ) in your server.

hope it might works.

```
  var newRentalUrl = serverURL;
        var dataObj = JSON.stringify(JSONDATA);

    $http.put(newRentalUrl, dataObj, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      },
    }).success(function(responseData) {
      try {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(responseData);
        //$state.go('payment');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }

  $ionicLoading.hide();
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply, I had tried the same but not getting result.